# File uploads in ColdFusion 10's REST API framework

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to upload files to a REST endpoint in ColdFusion 10. I've tried a variety of approaches and none have worked...

- Specify a CFARGUMENT type="binary" to the CFFUNCTION that is the REST endpoint definition. This results in a CF REST API compile error.
- Submit a multipart/form-data POST/PUT request and use CFFILE to handle the file upload in the body of the CFFUNCTION. This causes the CF REST framework to not see any of the form-field parameters that are required by CFARGUMENT tags.
- Uploading the file to a separate endpoint that expects only the file and setting the HTTP content-type header to the file's MIME type. The CF REST framework rejects this because it wants a specific content-type (presumably multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

The REST endpoint definitions look something like this...

```
    <cffunction name="createDocument" access="remote" returnType="String" returnformat="JSON" httpMethod="POST" restPath="/document/">
      <cfargument name="Authorization" type="string" required="true" restargsource="Header">
      <cfargument name="folder" type="any" required="true" restargsource="Form">
      <cfargument name="cabinet" type="any" required="true" restargsource="Form">
      <cfargument name="filedata" type="bindary" required="true" restargsource="Form">
     [...]
     </cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@siromega I am not sure if you ever find a solution for this but I came across taffy.io that supports file uploads. If you did, could you please post an update?

Headers for the image field are different and content of the image field is in binary encoding.

https://github.com/atuttle/Taffy/wiki/So-you-want-to:-Upload-a-file-via-your-API

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up ditching the built-in CF REST API and went with Taffy. Works a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i have created a file upload API using ColdFusion REST. Here is a sample in which we are accepting a file (csv or excel) and converting it to json. We have registered this REST service in ColdFusion Administrator. The Parameter name against which the file is uploaded is fileParam.

```
component  output="false" restpath="/upload"
{

remote any function uploadFile() httpmethod="POST" consumes="multipart/form-data" produces="application/json" {
    destination = getTempDirectory();       
    uploadDetails = FileUpload(destination, "fileparam", "text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "overwrite");
    fileSeparator = "\";//make platform independent     
    filePath = uploadDetails.SERVERDIRECTORY & fileSeparator & uploadDetails.ATTEMPTEDSERVERFILE;
    cfspreadsheet(action = "read", src = filePath, excludeHeaderRow = false, query = "data");
    return serializejson(data);

}
}
```